# How can I fix "Freeform Size simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2" warnings?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4, warnings

Since a couple of weeks, I've been using XCode 4.2 with projects created with previous XCode 3.x versions.

When creating some custom iPad views, I often use the "freeform" attribute of Interface Builder to be able to have views with an arbitrary size.

But then, I get build the following build warnings: "warning: Attribute Unavailable: Freeform Size simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2."

My question is: how can I fix these warnings?

ps: First, I assumed it meant my project wouldn't be backward-compatible with earlier versions of XCode (which doesn't bother me at all) and tried to tell Xcode so, by setting the Project Format to XCode 4.2-compatible only. Unfortunately, the dropdown menu for the project format only suggests "XCode 3.2-compatible" and "XCode 3.1-compatible".

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Open the .xib file in question and show the Utilities pane. Click on the File Inspector tab and under Interface Builder Document you'll see a Development field. Change it to Xcode 4.2.

[image: Xcode / IB Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dropdown list shows a "Default version" set to 4.1. Do you have any idea where this parameter can be changed to 4.2?

Comment: @DirtyHenry I have "Xcode 4.2" as the second entry, right under "Default version (Xcode 4.1)". I missed it first, too.

Comment: Thanks @geon. Actually I got the XCode 4.2 too but I'd like to change the default value from XCode 4.1 to XCode 4.2.

Comment: I wanted to post a quick "Thank you" as well.  This has been annoying me for about a week.  Simply and easy to fix.

Comment: Interesting -- mine is set to **Project SDK Version (iOS 5.0)**, yet I still get the warning.

Comment: @Answerbot: Look at the Development-Dropdown, not at the Deployment

Comment: thanks @Kyle O'Brien, it solved the warning but i wanted to know the reason why i was getting. I have a number of views, I am getting this warning only for 2 out of all.