# warning: Attribute Unavailable: Freeform Size simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2

Tags: uiview, warnings, xcode4.2, uipopovercontroller

This question has already been asked at: [How can I fix "Freeform Size simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2" warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054961/how-can-i-fix-freeform-size-simulated-metrics-are-not-available-prior-to-xcode). But the solution did not work for me.

I'm displaying a UIView in a popover and I'm getting the warning "Freeform Size simulated metrics are not available prior to Xcode 4.2"

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with iOS5. Under "Interface Builder Document" of the UIView, Development is set to Xcode 4.2 and Deployment set to iOS 5.0.

I've also tried playing around with the different sizing/positioning options for the view.

The UIView is 206 by 212. Here is the code to display it:

```
NumericPad* content = [[NumericPad alloc] init];    

UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                 initWithContentViewController:content];
aPopover.delegate = self;

// Store the popover in a custom property for later use.
popoverController = aPopover;

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:answerTextBox.bounds
                                   inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                 animated:YES];
```

I can easily resize the view to its correct size after it has been added to the popover, but I would rather solve the warning. I've also tried doing a clean build.

## Edit:

**Issue appears to have solved itself.** I don't know what I've done, but the warning has suddenly disappeared.