# Defines Presentation context is not available prior to xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4, ios5, xib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.2 Warnings when dropping Nav Controller on Tab Bar in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625731/xcode-4-2-warnings-when-dropping-nav-controller-on-tab-bar-in-ib)

I've been trying to open up a sample that is kind of close to the app that I'm trying to build, but when I go to mainWindow.xib and customize the tab bar that was already there, It just doesn't update when I build and run the app. The tab bar just does not change as if I was not saving the xib file.
It gives me...

"Defines Presentation context is not available prior to xcode 4.2"

That happened after I changed the target so I could get along with the new app.

Does that mean I just can't grab a sample and move on from there ?

How do I make it work ?

Comment: What version of XCode do you have?

Comment: I'm using Xcode version 4.2 and an old "Recipe" sample (downloaded from apple) - and I know that the sample was originally made in xcode 3.2 probably

Comment: Read this link, it may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625731/xcode-4-2-warnings-when-dropping-nav-controller-on-tab-bar-in-ib