# Attribute Unavailable: Defines Presentation Context is not available prior to Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.2 Warnings when dropping Nav Controller on Tab Bar in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625731/xcode-4-2-warnings-when-dropping-nav-controller-on-tab-bar-in-ib)

Every time I create a UINavigationController with interface builder
there will be a warning:

Attribute Unavailable: Defines Presentation Context is not available prior to Xcode 4.2.

I know I can just uncheck Defines context in Navigation Controller to avoid this warning

but I want to know

I am using Xcode 4.2 and working on ios5

why this warning would show up??

and what's different if I check or uncheck Defines Context??

Comment: Couldn't it be that the warning is just there to warn you that you're generating code that's not compatible with an earlier version of the IDE?

Comment: I found the answer thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054961/how-can-i-fix-freeform-size-simulated-metrics-are-not-available-prior-to-xcode

Interface builder default setting is Xcode 4.1

that's the problem